# Understanding HOF with default parameter in TypeScript map

Tags: javascript, typescript, higher-order-functions

I'm using HOFs in a JS/TS map. And my function has a default parameter.
`map` seems to convert array elements to a function list argument.
Can you please explain deeper for me?

I did a few simple examples here

Single element in array:

```
function add(a: number, b: number = 1) {
    console.log(b) // 0
    return a + b
}

console.log([1].map(add)) // [1]
```

Multiple elements in array:

```
function add(a: number, b: number = 1) {
    console.log(b) // 1,2
    return a+b
}

console.log([1,2,3].map(add)) // [1, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **[JS map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?retiredLocale=vi) receive a callback function with three arguments in that callback:**

```
map<U>(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U, thisArg?: any): U[];
```

- The current element is being processed in the array.
- The index of the current element being processed in the array.
- The array map was called upon

**So when you put this inside the map function, it works as a callback function:**

```
function add(a: number, b: number = 1) {
    console.log(b) // 0
    return a + b
}
```

**This also means this in meaningful naming:**

```
function add(currentValue: number, index: number) {
    return currentValue + index;
}
```

As I wrote earlier, a is `The current element is being processed in the array` and b is `The index of the current element being processed in the array`.

**So your functions above are similar to this:**

```js
console.log([1].map((a, b) => a + b))
console.log([1,2,3].map((a, b) => a + b));
```

**Or this, with more meaningful argument naming:**

```js
console.log([1].map((currentValue, index) => currentValue + index))
console.log([1,2,3].map((currentValue, index) => currentValue + index));
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. It makes sense.

Comment: You could consider to vote/mark accepted if the answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you see the map syntax is

```
map((element, index, array) => { ... } )
```

**element**
The current element being processed in the array.

**indexOptional**
The index of the current element being processed in the array.

**arrayOptional**
The array map was called upon.

You function

```
function add(a: number, b: number = 1) {
  console.log(b) // 0
  return a + b
}
console.log([1].map(add)) // [1]
```

Its accepting

element => a

indexOptional => b

So What you doing is adding array value with its index, your b will never be assigned to 1 because you always get index with the element.

In the above call, your

a will be 1 (actual array first element)

b will be 0 (index of first element)

the result you are getting is 1+0 = 1

Similarly happening for Multiple elements in array

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. It makes sense.